# Zend PHP - Old Version Upgrade?

Tags: php, zend-framework, version, legacy

Is it possible to upgrade Zend Version 1.10 to the latest version?  Also, I assume I can't upgrade the PHP version (5.2 currently) to the latest as I'm running an Older Zend Version.

Can someone give me some insight here?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to upgrade to the last released version of ZF 1.x. (1.12.20) with minimal changes. I would expect this ZF version to work on PHP 7.

There are some [docs for migrating a ZF1 app to ZF2](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/migration/overview.html) (not ZF3), but this is no small task (basically a rewrite of your application).

Both your ZF version and PHP version are past end of life (i.e. no longer receiving updates), so it's good that you are planning an upgrade.